# Vaadin Grid refresh issue

Tags: vaadin8

I'm using Vaadin Framework 8.0.6

I have the following workflow :

- Display grid with DataProvider and function DataProvider.fromCallbacks for lazy loading
- Update one item of this grid via a form displayed in a window
- Save the updated item, close window and call dataProvider.refreshAll()
- Grid is now up to date and show the new data in the corresponding row

So far everything is ok but when I select and only when I select the row of the updated item, it will display the old data of the item.

To do some tests, I have created next to the grid a button to call dataProvider.refreshAll()
When I click on it, the data is refreshed and up to date again
but after, if  I select the row of the updated item, it displays the old data again

Any idea ? is it a cache problem ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. To be sure, can you provide a SSCCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, after updating to Vaadin 8.1.0, this issue has disappeared.